# JavaFX: Preloader doesn't show up before Application

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, preloader

Tutorial I'm following: http://acodigo.blogspot.com/2016/03/javafx-preloader-pantalla-de-carga.html

My preloader doesn't show up before my application when I hit run inside of Eclipse, or when I click on my runnable jar I exported.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/htha9587/d42badd8ff2df0cc1632dbbc19e1ee5e

Could this be one way to make it show up?: I could try adding this method to MainLoader.java:

```
@Override public void init () throws Exception 
{
    Thread . Sleep (2500); 
}
```

Any reason why this is happening, and how I can solve It?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I looked over your question if I understand correctly you would like to see the your Preloader screen.

Your `thread.sleep()` command causes the Preloader also to sleep. If you like to see it you need to add another intensive task like

```
@Override public void init () throws Exception{
    int COUNT_LIMIT = 40000;
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT_LIMIT; i++) {
        double progress = (100 * i) / COUNT_LIMIT;
        LauncherImpl.notifyPreloader(this, new Preloader.ProgressNotification(progress));
    }
}
```

This should do the trick maybe increase `COUNT_LIMIT` to something that is even higher - maybe `(10^10)`.